# I need help in Python Spell checker

Tags: python

```
from spellchecker import SpellChecker
spell = SpellChecker()
misspelled = spell.unknown(['let', 'us', 'wlak','on','the','groun'])
for word in misspelled:
    print(spell.correction(word))
print(spell.candidates(word))
```

this is the program. I'm getting the following error

> ValueError: The provided dictionary language (en) does not exist

Comment: Provide the code which you have tried.

Comment: Edit the question with this code, Nobody can help with this unreadable mess.

Comment: Where exactly comes SpellChecker from - and why do you not simply supply an dictionary for `en` as the error suggests you do (because you miss it): ValueError: **The provided dictionary language (en) does not exist!**

Comment: I install the library pyspellchecker. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_spelling_check.htm

Comment: Any help  please?

Answer (score 1):

If you installed the package using

```
pip install pyspellchecker
```

You need to uninstall it since for 2.7 it doesn't automatically install the language packs.

```
pip uninstall pyspellchecker
```

Then you should reinstall it using

```
git clone https://github.com/barrust/pyspellchecker.git
cd pyspellchecker
python setup.py install
```

if you rerun your program, it should now work but I guess you need to tweak it slightly if you want to get candidates for each word in your loop.

```
from spellchecker import SpellChecker
spell = SpellChecker()
misspelled = spell.unknown(['let', 'us', 'wlak','on','the','groun'])
for word in misspelled:
    print(spell.correction(word))
    print(spell.candidates(word))
```